# Перенос временной папки в другое место

Tags: windows, администрирование

Можно ли перенести временную папку с диска С в другое место, прозрачно для всех программ?

Comment: Либо симлинк, либо сменить обе переменные окружения `TMP` и `TEMP`. Первый вариант пройдёт даже для программ, в которых хардкодом прошит путь к папке.

Comment: Добавлю, что стандартный виндовый бэкап может симлинк поломать. Будь осторожен.

Answer (score 3):

Предварительно создать TempFolder на D и:

```
mklink /D c:\TempFolder d:\TempFolder
```